# Is there any software like Carnac in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I'm using [Carnac](http://www.itsprite.com/carnac-let-your-keyboard-operation-display-on-your-screen-in-time/) to show the keyboard operation in my Windows Screen.
If there is a workshop related with vim usage, this tool useful definitely.

However, I will have a vim workshop in Ubuntu, I want to know is there any tool in Ubuntu like Carnac?

---

After [investigation](http://happycasts.net/episodes/9?autoplay=true), here is keyboard screen-display tools in MAC, named [keycastr](http://download.cnet.com/KeyCastr/3000-2075_4-125977.html)

And, [keymon](http://www.wings3d.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=216) (Display Keyboard and Mouse Status) for Linux, it can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Screenkey](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey) is what you are looking for. An old version can be found on repo:

```
sudo apt install screenkey
```

[image]

[This](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2010/08/see-what-you-type-screencast-your-keys.html) is a good website about it - it focuses on when you are sharing your screen, and need others to see what you press.
<sup><sub>[Kudos @Marslso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506586/is-there-any-software-like-carnac-in-ubuntu/506591#comment683113_506591)</sub></sup>

Comment: By the way, I found [a great website](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2010/08/see-what-you-type-screencast-your-keys.html) for screenkey introduction :)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this doesn't work very well on i3. I don't imagine it'll work well with other tiling window managers, either.

Comment: The website of screenkey is: http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/screenkey/